# How would you explain Functional Integration to an 8 year old?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, functional-calculus

I get the definition of the Functional Integral, but what heuristic interpretations are available to better understand the integral?

For instance, what motivates the definition? How is it related to the Functional Derivative?

Also, how would you explain this concept in a way an 8 year old would understand. For instance, with regular integration, the interpretation is area. Is there a geometric/probabilistic interpretation that can be readily explained with a picture/analogy?

Comment: May we assume the knowledge of finite-dimensional integration and some familiarity with function spaces?

Comment: Use a contour map and show how to determine how much rock is in a mountain (skip Reiman and go for the jugular with Lesbegue !).

Comment: Maybe this is not a relevant comment but I really can't help saying that I really wouldn't.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple you can assume the "8 year old" knows the heuristic interpretation of integrals up to 4d, and that function spaces are what they sound like to the "8-year old". If posting some math *with* the intuition helps the latter, go for it, I do understand about 60-80% of it :)

Comment: @Blazej I don't know. If it happens to come up, I'd explain it, if you're eight or adult or mathematically illiterate.

Comment: That was a joke, there is an answer to your question below ;-)

Comment: You may suggest to the kid to estimate the arrival time of his drunk mother (my tribute to gender equality) from a bar to her mathematically illiterate child following a random trajectory with variable speed.

Comment: *How would you explain Functional Integration to an 8 year old ?* - I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral gives the area under the graph of a function $f(x)$. However, the integral can also give the average value of a function. Reviewing the definition of the summation definition of the integral, which cuts up the function into rectangles and then sums them, we see that there is a relationship between the summation and the average value formula. Namely,

$$A(f(x))={1 \over {b-a}} \cdot \int_a^b f(x) \ dx$$

Where $A(f(x))$ is the average value of $f(x)$ over the interval $[a,b]$.

Now, the Functional Integral sums up the tiny contributions from an infinite number of functions, in much the same way a regular integral sums up rectangles. The difference is that the regular integral sums up differences between a single function over a tiny interval. The functional integral sums up the difference in a functional over tiny differences between different functions. What's a Functional? A functional is very similar to a function, except for one key difference. A functional takes a *function* as it's input where as a function takes a *single* value as its input. We denote a functional by $F[f]$. An example would be the number that represents the change in $f(t)$ over an interval.

$$F[f]=f(b)-f(a)=\Delta f$$

The Functional Integral simply gives the average value of a Functional.

Here's an example. If you have a functional that returns the average value of an arbitrary function, that is bounded to $[0,1]$, over the region $[0,1]$, the functional integral will give the average value of the functional. In this case it happens to be $1/2$.

That means the average of the average value of an *arbitrary* function confined to the unit square is ${1 \over 2}$. Pretty cool if you think about it!

Answer (score 0):

Functional integration is a collection of results in mathematics and physics where the domain of an integral is no longer a region of space, but a space of functions.

Answer (score 0):

One of motivations is in physics (quantum mechanics), where you sum over all possible trajectories that a system could follow to get a probability of finding it in specific place (knowing probability distribution at earlier time). I've heard this approach is also used in probability theory to describe brownian motions.

It really is just a sum, only with bigger amount of summands. Just like regular integral. Except it's more difficult to visualize, calculate and even precisely define.

Comment: It's the visualization that I'm interested in though. For instance, knowing what occurs to an arbitrary functional put through the functional integration, would be good. A random function integrated gives area. I don't think a random functional integrated always gives probabilities over all trajectories.